# Connected Monitor Name

Tags: java, c++, display

I'm developing an application that use an additional monitor ( a Wacom Tablet).
I need to identify where it is placed but the DisplayName i gather from java code are always Display 0, Display 1 etc...
i tried using a small c++ to get the System display:

```
void DumpDevice(const DISPLAY_DEVICE& dd, size_t nSpaceCount)
{   
    printf("%*sDevice Name: %s\n", nSpaceCount, "", dd.DeviceName);
    printf("%*sDevice String: %s\n", nSpaceCount, "", dd.DeviceString);
    printf("%*sState Flags: %x\n", nSpaceCount, "", dd.StateFlags);
    printf("%*sDeviceID: %s\n", nSpaceCount, "", dd.DeviceID);
    printf("%*sDeviceKey: ...%s\n\n", nSpaceCount, "", dd.DeviceKey + 42);
}

int main()
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;

    dd.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);

    DWORD deviceNum = 0;
    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, deviceNum, &dd, 0)){
        DumpDevice(dd, 0);
        DISPLAY_DEVICE newdd = { 0 };
        newdd.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
        DWORD monitorNum = 0;
        while (EnumDisplayDevices(dd.DeviceName, monitorNum, &newdd, 0))
        {
            DumpDevice(newdd, 4);
            monitorNum++;
        }
        puts("");
        deviceNum++;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

(I get this code from another answer here on stack overflow but i don't remember the page to link to it).

The output, anyway, is really not usefull:

```
Device Name: \
Device String: I
State Flags: 5
DeviceID: P
DeviceKey: ...\

    Device Name: \
    Device String: G
    State Flags: 3
    DeviceID: M
    DeviceKey: ...\


Device Name: \
Device String: I
State Flags: 1
DeviceID: P
DeviceKey: ...\

    Device Name: \
    Device String: G
    State Flags: 3
    DeviceID: M
    DeviceKey: ...\


Device Name: \
Device String: I
State Flags: 1
DeviceID: P
DeviceKey: ...\

    Device Name: \
    Device String: G
    State Flags: 3
    DeviceID: M
    DeviceKey: ...\


Device Name: \
Device String: I
State Flags: 8000000
DeviceID: P
DeviceKey: ...\


Device Name: \
Device String: I
State Flags: 0
DeviceID: P
DeviceKey: ...\


Device Name: \
Device String: I
State Flags: 0
DeviceID: P
DeviceKey: ...\
```

Any hint hot to solve this?

Edit: all this is needed in a Java application, i'm using c++ to create a simple wrap and the use JNI to call my wrap. If exista a better way to do this without passing from c++ is better.

Comment: If you are using C++, then why the `java` tag?

Comment: explained in Edit @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Have a look at `GraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getScreenDevices--  and the `GraphicsDevice` class

Comment: Is your C++ program compiled using ANSI or Unicode ? DISPLAY_DEVICE uses TCHAR, which is a wide character type on Unicode, which "%s" in printf cannot possibly print. Only the first character is shown because the second byte is always 0.

Comment: I use Unicode, o have to Switch on ANSI?

Comment: Already done @a_horse_with_no_name and the result was: Display 0, Display 1, Display 2

Comment: @SirDarius solved using different Coding, thanks! But now all display are: generic PnP . How can i obtain the real name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed to ANSII charset and now the output is the following (thanks to SirDarius for the hint):

```
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY1
Device String: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
State Flags: 5
DeviceID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_05CB1028&REV_0B
DeviceKey: ...\Control\Video\{80DB7D25-0399-49FD-A13A-F5FEAD8FCC0B}\0000

    Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0
    Device String: Generic PnP Monitor
    State Flags: 3
    DeviceID: MONITOR\AUO133D\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0003
    DeviceKey: ...\Control\Class\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0003


Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY2
Device String: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
State Flags: 1
DeviceID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_05CB1028&REV_0B
DeviceKey: ...\Control\Video\{80DB7D25-0399-49FD-A13A-F5FEAD8FCC0B}\0001

    Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY2\Monitor0
    Device String: Generic PnP Monitor
    State Flags: 3
    DeviceID: MONITOR\DELA0B9\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0004
    DeviceKey: ...\Control\Class\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0004


Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY3
Device String: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
State Flags: 1
DeviceID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_05CB1028&REV_0B
DeviceKey: ...\Control\Video\{80DB7D25-0399-49FD-A13A-F5FEAD8FCC0B}\0002

    Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY3\Monitor0
    Device String: Generic PnP Monitor
    State Flags: 3
    DeviceID: MONITOR\WAC1039\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0006
    DeviceKey: ...\Control\Class\{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0006


Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY4
Device String: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
State Flags: 8000000
DeviceID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_05CB1028&REV_0B
DeviceKey: ...\Control\Video\{80DB7D25-0399-49FD-A13A-F5FEAD8FCC0B}\0003


Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY5
Device String: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
State Flags: 8000000
DeviceID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_05CB1028&REV_0B
DeviceKey: ...\Control\Video\{80DB7D25-0399-49FD-A13A-F5FEAD8FCC0B}\0004


Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY6
Device String: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
State Flags: 8000000
DeviceID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_05CB1028&REV_0B
DeviceKey: ...\Control\Video\{80DB7D25-0399-49FD-A13A-F5FEAD8FCC0B}\0005
```

How can i see the Friendly name of the monitor, all are Showed as Generic PnP!